# how get embed ID from liveleak.com

Tags: php, curl

I wanna get ID  embed from liveleak.com.I wrote this code:

```
$url = 'http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=327_1392119908';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('/ll_embed\?f\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $result, $m);
//echo $result;
var_dump($m);
```

And It's working but the problem is embed display after click button and my code can't see it.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does "embed display after click button and my code can't see it" mean?  What is the actual issue here?

Comment: I believe he wants the output that's written to the page after the `Embed Code` button is pressed, but it isn't present there initially.

Comment: embed code is generate by javascript `<a class="form_button" href="javascript://" onclick="$(this).parent().html(generate_embed_code_generator_html('a089142f213c'))"><span>Embed Code</span></a>`.It isn't visable in html structure before you click button  under movie player.

Comment: @user3301891: Ah!  If the HTML is added via JavaScript then scraping the source with cURL isn't going to help here.  You need to use a headless browser (possibly phantomjs or similar).

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think in this example it's simpler than that, the embed code doesn't really change (apart from arbitrary height/width parameters), the ID for the embed could be retrieved via cURL, and then placed into a stored template iframe.

Comment: @MLeFevre: I guess.  Or he might be able to parse out the code from the `onclick` attribute.  I'm probably overthinking this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the embed code it gives you, you can make it yourself. If you look at the button itself the element looks like this

```
<a class="form_button" onclick="$(this).parent().html(generate_embed_code_generator_html('72415bff2b36'))" href="javascript://">
```

emphasis on this bit `generate_embed_code_generator_html('72415bff2b36')` as that is the part you should be looking for. Perform a regex and obtain the ID that's used in their js function `72415bff2b36`. eg:

```
preg_match("/generate_embed_code_generator_html\(\'([^']*)/", $result, $m);
echo $m[1]; // 72415bff2b36
```

the embed iframe looks like

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.liveleak.com/ll_embed?f=[ID]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

so simply feed the ID you regex'd for into it

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.liveleak.com/ll_embed?f=72415bff2b36" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and you'll end up with what they would give you.

Comment: @user3301891 please accept answer if it works for you.